# matching regex not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

been at this for an hour, could someone help?

trying to match in order to get one url from this kind of input:

```
www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htmwww.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htmwww.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htmwww.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm
```

which is taken from a textbox.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="urls"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(preg_match("/[^www]{3}.[a-zA-Z0-9\/\._]+\/\.htm$/", $_POST['urls'], $matches))
{
    echo 'yay';
}

?>
```

what i want from the preg_match is: `www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm`

Comment: Why not just simplify: `preg_match("/^.+?\.htm$/", $_POST['urls'], $matches);`

Comment: i want to split them after the match, so i want to start with 'www.'. i.e. i want to collect each url within the textbox

Comment: But you're not capturing anything in `$matches`. If you want www you can use: `preg_match("/^www\..+?\.htm$/", $_POST['urls'], $matches);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple regex:

```
w{3}.+htm
```

The whole command:

```
preg_match("/w{3}.+htm/", $_POST['urls'], $matches)
```

[Online Test](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3n0)

Comment: Why use `w{3}` when just `www` is clearer and shorter?

Comment: @Qtax I agree; this is more like a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `preg_match("/^w{3}.[a-zA-Z0-9\/\._]+\.htm$/", $_POST['urls'], $matches)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a split using a regex:

```
$links = preg_split("/(?=www\.)/", "www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htmwww.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htmwww.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htmwww.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm");
print_r($links);
```

`(?=www\.)` is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and will match, when there is "www." ahead in the string.

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm 
               [2] => www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm 
               [3] => www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm 
               [4] => www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(w{3}.+?\.htm)
```

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/sE4iB3)